# Getting error in package.json while uploading to Openshift server

Tags: node.js, openshift, package.json

I am getting following error when i am trying to push my application to Openshift server. I have updated only package.json and trying to upload it on server then it showing this error.

[image]

So i have written couple of command to find out this error. So i found the following error but i am not getting what should i do now to fix this error.

[image]

My package.json is following below. If you think that there is some error in this package.json, please inform me. It is running fine on localhost but i do not know it is not able to find out package.json.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that the existing running application is not getting stopped correctly.  Try using the rhc app stop command to completely stop your application, and then ssh to your gear (rhc ssh) and use the "ps -ef" command to make sure nothing else is running that would be taking up that port.

Comment: after executing these commands, i got the following result. Please help me to resolve this issue.                                                                                            UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY                                                                       3434     203281 203218  0 16:54 ?                                                                      3434     203285 203281  1 16:54 pts/0                                                               3434     203682 203285  2 16:54 pts/0